# Finishing nails into treated lumber indoors... a disaster waiting to happen?

Tags: kitchens, lumber

We framed out our new kitchen island with some leftover lumber, some of which is treated. Our cabinets came with some extra skin, which is roughly 1/8" thick, and we already attached it to our island with some interior finishing nails. After the fact I read that the finishing nails are not recommended for treated lumber. Since this application is indoor only, am I still OK? Do I need to extract the finishing nails and replace them with SS or galvanized?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of treated wood are you using?

Comment: Treated lumber is not recommended for interior use.

Comment: Exterior treated lumber. It's basically what they sell at lowes that's opposite of the non treated wood. Also since it's hidden behind the skin of the island I figured it wouldn't be a big deal. It's not touching food or anything.

Comment: Also the bottom plate needed to be treated since it's right on the concrete slab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you notice discoloration in a couple of decades would I remove them. They won't be getting wet so the chemicals won't be active nor re-activated. I've used scraps for decades of even the really toxic stuff & still don't have any side-effect from using finish nails, common nails, plain wood screws & even staples for casement window porch screens in 2x2 PT frames.